# Coroutinescope launches but data isn't updated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

This is my fragment code:

```
class DrinkWaterFragment : ScopedFragment(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein by closestKodein()

    private val viewModelFactory: DrinkWaterViewModelFactory by instance<DrinkWaterViewModelFactory>()
    private lateinit var viewModel: DrinkWaterViewModel
    private lateinit var picker: MaterialDatePicker<*>

    private lateinit var waterLogs: LiveData<List<WaterLog>>
    private val dates = MutableLiveData<Pair<Long, Long>>()

    val job = Job()
    val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

    /* onCreateView and onCreateOptionsMenu exist */

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(DrinkWaterViewModel::class.java)

        launch {
            initializePicker()
            execute()
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.pick_date_range -> {
                picker.show(parentFragmentManager, picker.toString())
                    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener { selection ->
                    val x = selection as Pair<Long, Long>
                    dates.postValue(x)
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    private suspend fun initializePicker() {
        val today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()

        picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
            .setSelection(Pair(today, today))
            .setTheme(resolveOrThrow(requireContext(), R.attr.materialCalendarTheme))
            .setTitleText(R.string.pick_date_range)
            .build()
    }

    private suspend fun execute() {
        waterLogs = viewModel.waterLogs(Date().time, Date().time).await()

        dates.observeForever{ value ->
            uiScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                waterLogs = viewModel.waterLogs(value.first!!, value.second!!).await()
                println(value)
            }
        }

        waterLogs.observeForever { m ->
            println("In")
            println(m.size)
        }

        waterLogs.observeForever { wLs ->
            Log.i("Dated", wLs!!.size.toString())
            water_log_recycler_view.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(
                4, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL
            )
            water_log_recycler_view.adapter = WaterLogAdapter(context, wLs)
            water_log_recycler_view.onItemClick{recyclerView, position, v ->
                Log.i("Click", "B")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. From the `onActivityCreated`, I `launch` two functions: `initializePicker()` and `execute()`.
2. `execute()` calls the `ViewModel`'s `waterLogs()` method with the same parameters. Here is the code of the ViewModel's function:

```
    fun waterLogs(start: Long, end: Long) = deferred {
        Log.i("IN", "Hello")
        waterRepository.getWaterLogs(
            Date(start).apply { hours = 0; minutes = 0; seconds = 0; }.time,
            Date(end).apply { hours = 23; minutes = 59; seconds = 59 }.time
        )
    }
```

3. The `ViewModel` calls `waterLogs()` method present inside my `Repository` method with the same parameters, from which the DB query happens using Room DAO. Here's the code from the Repository:

```
suspend fun getWaterLogs(start: Long, end: Long): LiveData<List<WaterLog>> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println("IN1")
        return@withContext waterDao.getWaterLog(start, end)
    }
}
```

4. I can confirm `execute()` works because I can see the Recycler View of my fragment getting updated and also seeing the following in the logcat:

```
2020-06-28 00:07:27.888 30934-31013/me.sparker0i.drinkwater I/IN: Hello
2020-06-28 00:07:27.892 30934-31013/me.sparker0i.drinkwater I/System.out: IN1
2020-06-28 00:07:28.038 30934-30934/me.sparker0i.drinkwater I/System.out: In
2020-06-28 00:07:28.038 30934-30934/me.sparker0i.drinkwater I/System.out: 23
2020-06-28 00:07:28.038 30934-30934/me.sparker0i.drinkwater I/Dated: 23
```

Now within this same Fragment when I call the `picker.show()` (Triggered from a menu item) which shows me a `MaterialDatePicker` dialog. When I do a particular selection of a Date Range from this and Press OK, I do see the following lines in my logcat:

```
2020-06-28 00:11:22.303 2191-2380/me.sparker0i.drinkwater I/IN: Hello
2020-06-28 00:11:22.304 2191-2380/me.sparker0i.drinkwater I/System.out: IN1
2020-06-28 00:11:22.305 2191-2191/me.sparker0i.drinkwater I/System.out: Pair{1593216000000 1593216000000}
```

It means that the picker's onpositivebuttonclicklistener did get triggered and both the ViewModel and Repository also got triggered. But I believe the dao is also getting called but is unable to update on the recyclerview as `waterLogs.observeForever` isn't getting triggered when I set dates from the picker.

Is there any way to get this working? If anyone wants to have a look at my GitHub repo, please check the `canary` branch where I have updated [this code](https://github.com/Sparker0i/Water-Drink/tree/canary)

Comment: Can you move your observers out of suspend function and see what result you get

Comment: the `LiveData` objects `waterLogs` gets initialized within the `suspend`ed `execute()` function. Moving it out of there throws a Not initialized error..

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to mix coroutines and LiveData like this. Normally coroutines are started from the viewModel. You should return `Flow<List<WaterLog>>` from your repository rather than `LiveData`. Coroutines here are actually doing nothing for you, except delaying your fetching of LiveData that you actually use. Either use coroutines in your viewModel AND repository AND dao, or remove them altogether and exclusively use `LiveData` and your life will be simpler.